# Exporting a datatable to PDF using c# 4.0

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, export-to-pdf

I want to export the data of a datatable into PDF without using any third party dll.
I am working on .net 4.0 framework with c#

Answer (score 2):

That's going to be tough.

I am not sure if your requirement to avoid third party dlls applies to SSRS, but if not then you could create an SSRS report and export the report as a pdf.